# Wrong url is getting matched

Tags: python, django, url

I simply want to get to another directory than index.

What I think Django is doing after I type in "`localhost:8000/ysynch/`":

1. Checking "`ysynch/urls.py`" (my root urls.py file)
2. Finding "`ytlinks/`" including "`links.urls`"
3. Matching with "`ytlinks/`" (in file "links.urls") and calling "`views.ytlinks`"

But instead, views.index is called. Where am I doing a mistake?

root\urls.py

C:\Users\xyron\Desktop\ysynch\ysynch\urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^ytlinks/', include('links.urls')),
    url(r'^$', include('links.urls')),
]
```

links\urls.py

C:\Users\xyron\Desktop\ysynch\links\urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^ytlinks/', views.ytlinks, name='ytlinks'),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Comment: The [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#url-dispatcher) extensively covers that topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main part of your confusion is that you are expecting each urls.py to be trying to match the entire url, but instead you can think of `include` as doing a string concatenation and joining the previous parts of the url with the section of the url in the next urls.py

---

When django tries to match a url, it goes down the list of regexes until it finds one that matches so what you have is the following

```
r'^ytlinks/'   + r'^ytlinks/'   ==>  views.ytlinks
r'^ytlinks/'   + r'^$'   ==>  views.index
r'^$'          +  r'^ytlinks/'      ==>  views.ytlinks (not quite!)
r'^$'          +  r'^$'      ==>  views.index(not quite!)
```

So the first one of those that gets matched would be the second one for your url. `$` in regex means end of a string so it won't bother to check anything that follows it here so you can rule out the last two regexes.

So your fix is threefold,

1. The links/urls you need to remove the first regex

   ```
   url(r'^ytlinks/', views.ytlinks, name='ytlinks'),
   ```
2. You need to remove the $ from your inclusion url in the other urls.py

   ```
   url(r'^', include('links.urls')),
   ```
3. You need to modify the views that each link should go to so eventually you end up with the following

   root\urls.py

   ```
   urlpatterns = [
       url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
       url(r'^ytlinks/', include('links.urls')),
       url(r'^', views.index, name='index'),
   ]
   ```

   links\urls.py

   ```
   urlpatterns = [
       url(r'^$', views.ytlinks, name='ytlinks'),
   ]
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Because paths are added to inclusion

```
  url(r'^ytlinks/', include('links.urls')),
```

so you have following

```
# /ytlinks/ytlinks
url(r'^ytlinks/', views.ytlinks, name='ytlinks'),
# /ytlinks/
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
```

so when you call /ytlinks/ you get to the view inside ytlinks which is index view again

the view you want to present is /ytlinks/ytlinks/

Answer (score 2):

> Checking "ysynch/urls.py" (my root urls.py file)
>
> Finding "ytlinks/" including "links.urls"
>
> Matching with "ytlinks/" (in file "links.urls") and calling "views.ytlinks"

The already matched part of the url will be excluded from further matching inside your includes.

So you basicly try to match "ytlinks/" again which would be true for "ytlinks/ytlinks/". You just want to match like this in your `links\urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.ytlinks, name='ytlinks'),
]
```

All of your urls in this file already match the first part "ytlinks/" and you only have to match the rest which is nothing or `^$` in your case.